# PHP url link with variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass `$row['uuid']` to the end of a URL without success so that it opens up a new window to display the jpeg file which is located on a network drive.

The code I have been trying is

```
echo'<table border="1" ><th >Date and Time</th><th>Plate</th>   <th>Confidence</th><th>Image Name</th>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['dt'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['plate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['confidence'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='http://192.xxx.x.xx/Pictures/plates/.$row['uuid'] .' target='blank_'>" . $row['uuid'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The error I keep getting is:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

I have tried different ways to add `$row['uuid']` to the end of the URL with no success.

Answer (score 2):

You were just missing a `"` try this and see if it works

```
echo'<table border="1" ><th >Date and Time</th><th>Plate</th>      <th>Confidence</th><th>Image Name</th>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['dt'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['plate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['confidence'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='http://192.xxx.x.xx/Pictures/plates/'".$row['uuid'] ."' target='blank_'>" . $row['uuid'] . "</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi just do it without the dots:

```
echo'<table border="1" ><th >Date and Time</th><th>Plate</th>   <th>Confidence</th><th>Image Name</th>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['dt'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['plate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['confidence'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='http://192.xxx.x.xx/Pictures/plates/".$row['uuid']."' target='blank_'>" . $row['uuid'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

saftly add .jpg

```
echo "<td><a href='http://192.xxx.x.xx/Pictures/plates/".$row['uuid'].".jpg' target='blank_'>" . $row['uuid'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, but this solution also works: removing single quotes in $row...

Comment: thats perfect works a treat. If I wanted to add .jpg to the end of the .$row['uuid'].  hows the correct way to do this ?     echo "<td><a href='http://192.xx.xx.xx/Pictures/plates/".$row['uuid'].".jpg' target='blank_'>" . $row['uuid'] . "</a></td>"

Comment: updated answer please have a look

Comment: spot on thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

The problematic line obviously is this one:

```
echo "<td><a href='http://192.xxx.x.xx/Pictures/plates/.$row['uuid'] .' target='blank_'>" . $row['uuid'] . "</a></td>";
```

You are using 2 methods here to get your `$row['uuid']` into the string. The latter method, stopping the string and concatenating it with the `.` operator, works fine.

However, the first method, directly inserting it in a double-quoted string, does not work with array indices. Also, you do not need concatenation dots `.` there.
Either use the other method

```
echo "<td><a href='http://192.xxx.x.xx/Pictures/plates/" . $row['uuid'] . "' target='blank_'>" . $row['uuid'] . "</a></td>";
```

or encapsulate your variable inside the string with curly braces:

```
echo "<td><a href='http://192.xxx.x.xx/Pictures/plates/{$row['uuid']}' target='blank_'>" . $row['uuid'] . "</a></td>";
```